# Process for building a package to be managed by an offline conda/puppet environment

Tags: puppet, anaconda, conda

I’m trying build a package to be managed by an offline `conda` environment 
in Linux. I’m doing a dry run with `py4j`.

On my online build server:

1. I download the `py4j` recipe
2. And download the source distribution (`py4j-0.8.2.1.tar.gz`)
3. Copy the recipe and the source distribution to the offline puppet 
   server

On my offline puppet server:

1. tweak the recipe to point to my the copy of the source distribution.
2. `condabuildpy4j− conda install –use-local py4j`
3. `$ conda index linux-64`

`conda index linux-64` writes the `py4j` configuration to `repodata.json`. I 
can see `py4j` is in `repodata.json`. And there’s also a 
`py4j-0.8.2.1-py27_0.json` created under `/opt/anaconda/conda-meta/`

We have a custom channel mapped to `/srv/www/yum/anaconda_pkgs/`

```
$ cat .condarc 
channels: 
- http://10.1.20.10/yum/anaconda_pkgs/
```

I can see that `py4j` configuration is added to the following files:

```
./envs/_test/conda-meta/py4j-0.8.2.1-py27_0.json    
./pkgs/cache/ef2e2e6cbda49e8aeeea0ae0164dfc71.json    
./pkgs/py4j-0.8.2.1-py27_0/info/recipe.json    
./pkgs/py4j-0.8.2.1-py27_0/info/index.json    
./conda-bld/linux-64/repodata.json  ./conda-bld/linux-64/.index.json 
./conda-meta/py4j-0.8.2.1-py27_0.json
```

Can someone explain what each of these json files is supposed to do?

I can also see that there is a `repodata.json` and `.index.json` in 
`/srv/www/yum/anaconda_pkgs/linux-64` that were updated but don’t have a 
configuration for `py4j`.

I manually copied my `py4j-0.8.2.1.tar.gz` into my custom repo 
(channel) in `/srv/www/yum/anaconda_pkgs/linux-64`?

I still can’t do `conda install –use-local py4j` from host machines or 
`puppet agent -t`. I get the following:

```
err: /Stage[main]/Anaconda::Packages/Anaconda::Install_pkg[py4j]/Package[py4j]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of ‘/opt/anaconda/bin/conda install –yes –quiet py4j’ returned 1: Fetching package metadata: .. 
Error: No packages found in current linux-64 channels matching: py4j
```

You can search for this package on Binstar with

```
binstar search -t conda py4j
```

Comment: Is `py4j-0.8.2.1.tar.gz` a typo? It should be called `py4j-0.8.2.1-py27_0.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

`--use-local` only searches the `conda-bld/linux-64` channel. If you move the package to another local channel, you will need to add it to your `~/.condarc` `channels` as a `file://` url.

Whenever you add a package to a local repo, you need to run `conda index` on that directory. This will regenerate the `repodata.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer you question about the various json files, but note that you really don't need to care about any of these.

> ./envs/_test/conda-meta/py4j-0.8.2.1-py27_0.json

This is a remnant from the build process. Once the package is built, it is installed into a `_test` environment so that the actions in the `test` section of your `meta.yaml` can be run.  Each environment has a `conda-meta` directory that contains the metadata for each package installed in that environment.

> ./pkgs/cache/ef2e2e6cbda49e8aeeea0ae0164dfc71.json

Everything in the `pkgs` directory is a cache. This is a local cache of the channel repodata, so that conda doesn't have to redownload it when it is "fetching package metadata" if it hasn't changed.

> ./pkgs/py4j-0.8.2.1-py27_0/info/recipe.json

Again, this is a cache. When the `p4js` package is installed anywhere, it is extracted in the `pkgs` directory. Inside the package, in the `info` directory, is all the metadata for the package. This file is the metadata from the recipe that was used to create the package. Conda doesn't use this metadata anywhere, it is just included for convenience.

> ./pkgs/py4j-0.8.2.1-py27_0/info/index.json

This is the metadata of the package included in the package itself. It's what `conda index` will use to create the `repodata.json`.

> ./conda-bld/linux-64/repodata.json

This is the repo metadata for the special channel of packages you have built (the channel used with `--use-local`, and used by `conda build` automatically.

> ./conda-bld/linux-64/.index.json

This is a special cache file used internally by `conda index`.

> ./conda-meta/py4j-0.8.2.1-py27_0.json

This is similar to the first one. It's the environment metadata for the package that you installed into your root environment.